# Prevent Background Activity From Resuming

Tags: android

I have a app that sets the main Actvity as the main launcher. How can I prevent my current foreground Activity from closing whenever I press the Home Button which calls the background activity from the bottom of the stack. Is there a way to trap the intent and allow the the foreground ativitiy to finish. My manifest has the following:

android:launchMode="singleTask"

Comment: Why do you want the Activity to prevent the user from leaving?  If there's some background operation, can you put it in a Service or IntentService?

Comment: I want the user to finish the operation in that Activity screen before exiting out.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way within the public APIs to "override" the home button in the manner that you wish.